# node.getTextContent throws exception when called through Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm attempting to incorporate ckfinder into my Apache/Tomcat system. The problem I have is that when the Configuration file attempts to read the configuration.xml, it returns the nodes just fine, but calling getTextContent on the nodes throws an exception. I have run the exact same code through a local class and it works fine. It's only when trying to call the file through the website that it fails.

```
    File file = new File(getFullConfigPath());
    this.lastCfgModificationDate = file.lastModified();
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = db.parse(file);
    doc.normalize();
    Node node = doc.getFirstChild();
    logger.severe("init node - " + node);
    logger.severe("init value - " + node.getTextContent());
```

In this case, my output will get display the config node, but will throw an exception when it attempts the value line. The same happens if I try it on a child instead of the config node. I've attempted feeding it a relative URL, but it doesn't find the file, and an absolute URL gets an SSLHandshakeException since I'm using a secure server.

It seems odd that I can get the nodes fine, but not the contents of them. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was created by a compatability issue with xerces. More information can be found in this question's answer:

[java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.xerces.dom.ElementImpl.getTextContent()Ljava/lang/String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014989/java-lang-abstractmethoderror-org-apache-xerces-dom-elementimpl-gettextcontent)