# Jasper Report 5.5 runtime error

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have written a program to generate pdf reports by using *JasperReports 5.5* but when running the program following exception comes:

```
  Java.lang.AbstractMethodError: 
            org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredElementImpl.getTextContent()Ljava/lang/String; 
at       
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.parseFontFace(Simple‌​FontExtensionHelper.java:364) at 
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.parseFontFamily(Simp‌​leFontExtensionHelper.java:290) at 
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.parseFontFamilies(Si‌​mpleFontExtensionHelper.java:254)
```

Comment: You must show enough source for people to reproduce your problem.

Comment: in sort you should add more `StackTrace`and `code`  to Identify your Problem

Comment: This comes when executing this method : JasperRunManager.runReportToPdfFile(...) 
----------------------------------------------

java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredElementImpl.getTextContent()Ljava/lang/String;
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.parseFontFace(SimpleFontExtensionHelper.java:364)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.parseFontFamily(SimpleFontExtensionHelper.java:290)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.parseFontFamilies(SimpleFontExtensionHelper.java:254)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014989/java-lang-abstractmethoderror-org-apache-xerces-dom-elementimpl-gettextcontent

Answer (score 0):

```
public class AbstractMethodError extends IncompatibleClassChangeError
```

`AbstractMethodError` thrown when an application tries to call an `abstract` method. Normally, this `error` is caught by the `compiler`;

but this `error` can only occur at run time if the definition of some `class` has incompatibly changed since the currently executing method was last compiled.

> **Solution** - Please re-compile your code or Class(Which raise error) and then run your Code.

Comment: This comes when executing this method :
JasperRunManager.runReportToPdfFile(...) 

In details the exception is like this :

java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredElementImpl.getTextContent()Ljava/lang/String;
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.parseFontFace(SimpleFontExtensionHelper.java:364)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.parseFontFamily(SimpleFontExtensionHelper.java:290)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.parseFontFamilies(SimpleFontExtensionHelper.java:254)

Comment: then recompile your Code. and then try to run ..  @Manujaya

Comment: please add this stacktrace to your question. Thank you. @Manujaya