# getTextContent on xml node returning an exception

Tags: java, xml, dom

I am trying to get the content of an *xml node*, but this is what I get as output :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: 
org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredElementImpl.getTextContent()Ljava/lang/String;  
at cities2.main(cities2.java:74)
```

Here you can find the XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<repertoire>
<!-- John DOE -->
<personne sexe="masculin">
    <nom>DOE</nom>
    <prenom>John</prenom>
    <telephones>
        <telephone type="fixe">01 02 03 04 05</telephone>
        <telephone type="portable">06 07 08 09 10</telephone>
    </telephones>
</personne>
```

And then the code block :

```
import java.io.File;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class cities2 {
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    /*
     * Etape 1 : récupération d'une instance de la classe "DocumentBuilderFactory"
     */
    final DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

    try {
        /*
         * Etape 2 : création d'un parseur
         */
        final DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

    /*
     * Etape 3 : création d'un Document
     */
    final Document document= builder.parse(new File("cities2.xml"));



    /*
     * Etape 4 : récupération de l'Element racine
     */
    final Element racine = document.getDocumentElement();

    //Affichage de l'élément racine
    System.out.println("\n*************RACINE************");
    System.out.println(racine.getNodeName());

    /*
     * Etape 5 : récupération des personnes
     */
    final NodeList racineNoeuds = racine.getChildNodes();
    final int nbRacineNoeuds = racineNoeuds.getLength();

    for (int i = 0; i<nbRacineNoeuds; i++) {
        if(racineNoeuds.item(i).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            final Element personne = (Element) racineNoeuds.item(i);

        //Affichage d'une personne
        System.out.println("\n*************PERSONNE************");
        System.out.println("sexe : " + personne.getAttribute("sexe"));

            /*
         * Etape 6 : récupération du nom et du prénom
         */
        final Element nom = (Element) personne.getElementsByTagName("nom").item(0);
        final Element prenom = (Element) personne.getElementsByTagName("prenom").item(0);






        //Affichage du nom et du prénom
        System.out.println("nom : " + nom.getTextContent());
       System.out.println("prénom : " + prenom.getTextContent());

        /*
         * Etape 7 : récupération des numéros de téléphone
         */
        final NodeList telephones = personne.getElementsByTagName("telephone");
        final int nbTelephonesElements = telephones.getLength();

        for(int j = 0; j<nbTelephonesElements; j++) {
            final Element telephone = (Element) telephones.item(j);

                    //Affichage du téléphone
                    System.out.println(telephone.getAttribute("type") + " : " + telephone.getTextContent());
        }
        }               
    }           
    }
    catch (final ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (final SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (final IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
```

}

In fact, the problem concern both lines :

```
 //Affichage du nom et du prénom
    System.out.println("nom : " + nom.getTextContent());
   System.out.println("prénom : " + prenom.getTextContent());
```

The XML file is read and parsed, because we can get all outputs before this last one ( I mean  System.out.println("nom : " + nom.getTextContent());..). 
I use JDK 8u121, So it's updated, 
If you have any ideas it would be helpful.
Thank you

Comment: Where is the XML file

Comment: I am sorry. Please find the XML file and also the code block above. Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014989/java-lang-abstractmethoderror-org-apache-xerces-dom-elementimpl-gettextcontent

Comment: Thank you a lot. my problem was resolved through this solution

Comment: Please how can I add the tag as resolved problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The presence of `org.apache.xerces.dom` in the stacktrace indicates that you are not using the DOM implementation in the JRE, but Apache Xerces. You get this kind of exception if you are using a very old version of Xerces that doesn't implement DOM Level 3. Either remove Xerces (so that the DOM implementation from the JRE is used) or upgrade it to a newer version.