# how to fix the java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredElementNSImpl.getTextContent()Ljava/lang/String;

Tags: java, jar

This is the stacktrace I get when I run my application:

> Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
>   org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredElementNSImpl.getTextContent()Ljava/lang/String;
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.unmarshallers.PackagePropertiesUnmarshaller.readElement(PackagePropertiesUnmarshaller.java:146)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.unmarshallers.PackagePropertiesUnmarshaller.loadCreated(PackagePropertiesUnmarshaller.java:162)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.unmarshallers.PackagePropertiesUnmarshaller.unmarshall(PackagePropertiesUnmarshaller.java:124)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.getParts(OPCPackage.java:713)
>     at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:275)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:209)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:168)
>     at
>   Snomed.Snomed.ImportManualMappingUtility.importmanualmappingdata(ImportManualMappingUtility.java:191)
>     at
>   Snomed.Snomed.ImportManualMappingUtility.importSnomedRun(ImportManualMappingUtility.java:128)
>     at
>   Snomed.Snomed.ImportManualMappingUtility.run(ImportManualMappingUtility.java:100)

When I debug the java that contains the `ImportManualMappingUtility` class I get an error at the following line:

```
Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(loadFileConcept));
```

How can I fix this problem? I believe it is a problem related to xerces jar file; does it?

Comment: Your problem is described in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014989/java-lang-abstractmethoderror-org-apache-xerces-dom-elementimpl-gettextcontent

Comment: i tried removing all  the xerces files from the webinf /lib folder but that is resulting in some other error!!! plz help??

Comment: what version of poi do you use?

Comment: version 3.13 i also tried using the 3.9 poi jar file

Comment: Should be xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.11.0. Try to download from here and put in WEB-INF/lib folder: http://central.maven.org/maven2/xerces/xercesImpl/2.11.0/xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar

Comment: You may need xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01 as well: http://central.maven.org/maven2/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.4.01/xml-apis-1.4.01.jar

Comment: currently there is xerces-1.2.3, xerces-2.4.0 xercesImpl-2.6.2 xercesImpl-2.8.1

Comment: and xml-apis xml-apis-1.3.04 in my webinf/ lib folder

Comment: i downloaded those jar files..still no luck!!